# Definition and proof of Strict Stationarity

Tags: time-series, stationarity

The definition of strict stationarity I'm using is the following:

$(X_1,...,X_n)=^d(X_{1+h},...,X_{n+h})$, for any integer h, and positive integer n.

I'm trying to prove that $(X_1,X_{1+h})=^d(X_{t},X_{t+h})$ for any integer t, but the only close thing I managed to prove until now is that $(X_1,X_{t})=^d(X_{1+h},X_{t+h})$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the definition say when $h=t-1$ and $n=1+h$?

Comment: @whuber and what if $t$ is smaller than -1? $h$ could be negative, but $n$ cannot...

Comment: Where in your question is it stipulated that $t$ could be anything less than $1$?  Your notation strongly suggests the indexes of this process are $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @whuber ok, I'll edit the question. By the way, I forgot to say thanks for your interest in this question. :)

Comment: I wonder why the term "weak" is included in the title of the question? Nothing related to "weak" stationarity is included in the body of the question (and no, strict stationarity does not in general imply weak stationarity).

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: It's just that what I'm trying to prove is used in the proof of (strict +Existence of moments) => weak.

At least it is proved like this, in Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting by Brockwell and Davis, page 49-50.

Should I change the title?

Comment: I think changing the title is a good idea, because the question _per se_ is only the first step in what you write in your comment as ultimate proof target. Given the content of the question, it seems that an appropriate title would be "Definition and proof of Strict Stationarity".

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Why does strict stationarity _not_ imply weak stationarity in general? A strictly stationary process for which $E[X_t^2]$ is finite _is_ weakly stationary. It is only those processes for which $E[X_t^2]$ is not finite that fail to be weakly stationary (because we cannot define the autocovariance).

Comment: @DilipSarwate That's just exactly what I meant. I used "in general" in the sense "without further assumptions".  "Finiteness of moments up to 2nd order" is an assumption additional to strict stationarity. Perhaps I used wrongly the expression "in general"? (after all I am not a native English speaker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $i=1+h, j=n+h$, the definition of stationarity implies that the distribution of $(X_i,X_j)$ depends only on $j-i$ for all integers $i$ and $j$.  The result follows immediately.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate more on yourfirst sentence? I'm having a bit of difficulty. Thank you for your patience. ;)

Comment: It is a consequence of the facts that (1) $n-1 = (n+h)-(1+h)$; (2) when $h$ can be any integer and $n$ can be any positive integer, then $(i,j)=(1+h, n+h)$ can be any pair of integers provided $j\ge i$, because given $(i,j)$ you can solve for $(h,n)=(i-1,j-i+1)$; and (3) since the distribution of $(X_i,X_j)$ determines the distribution of $(X_j,X_i)$, we may always choose $j\ge i$.

Comment: On your second point, and from what I understand, you prove that $(X_1,X_n)=^d(X_{1+h},X_{n+h})=^d(X_{i},X_{j})$?

Comment: I don't really view this as a "proof" of anything: it is merely pointing out that what you want to conclude is just another way of interpreting the statement you started with.

Comment: But then may I conclude what I wrote in my comment above? I just want to be sure I understood your reasoning.